# Angular ui router How to change the html in view of a state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i am new to angular i want to create a nested view using angular ui router

i have index.html
in this

```
<div>
  <div ui-view="menu"></div>
  <div ui-view="content"></div>
   <div ui-view="footer"></div>
</div>
```

in my app.js i use this

```
 app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('public', {
        url: "",
        views: {
            'menu': {
                templateUrl: 'app/index/public.menu.html'
            },
            'content': {
                templateUrl: 'app/index/public.content.html'
            },
            'footer': {
                templateUrl: 'app/index/public.footer.html'
            }
        }
    })
   })
```

in content.html i have

```
<div>
    <div ui-view="status"></div>
</div>
```

i want to set default html to that view "status"

and i also want to lode the html according to the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/O8B7LH?p=preview)

And this is an extract, of the state definition update, supporting both:

- the `ui-view="content"` contains `ui-view="status"`
- the status url is generated dynamically by the url

State def:

```
 $stateProvider
    .state('public', {
      url : '/{name:[abc]}',
      views: {
        'menu': { templateUrl: 'public.menu.html', },
        'content': { templateUrl: 'public.content.html', },
        'footer': { template: '<div>footer content</div>', },
        'status@public': {
            templateUrl: function($stateParams){
              if($stateParams.name === "a"){
                return "a.tpl.html";
              } 
              if($stateParams.name === "b"){
                return "b.tpl.html"
              }
              return "c.tpl.html";
            },
        },
```

The biggest magic is in the `status@public` name definition, read more here:

- [View Names - Relative vs. Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names)

The template selection is driven by the feature:

- [Templates](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#templates)

Check the working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/O8B7LH?p=preview)

Comment: this is  what i exactly i need thanks for the quick reply @Radim Köhler and for the answer

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow! Enjoy `ui-router` ;)